# The default for KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, key-value

I have an object of the type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,U>> keyValueList`, I am using

```
 var getResult= keyValueList.SingleOrDefault();
 if(getResult==/*default */)
 {
 }
 else
 {
 }
```

How can I check whether `getResult` is the default, in case I can't find the correct element?

I can't check whether it is `null` or not, because `KeyValuePair` is a struct.

Comment: Here is a similar question with some interesting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/793897/323071

Comment: You can also say getResult.Key != null to check whether list is null as if it is the key will always be null

Comment: @pengibot That assumes the Key is nullable.

Answer (score 672, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (getResult.Equals(new KeyValuePair<T,U>()))
```

or this:

```
if (getResult.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<T,U>)))
```

Comment: You can use the concept of the "new" option here, but avoid having to re-specify the type: 

if (getResult.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(getResult.GetType())))

Comment: i think `if (getResult.Equals(default))` also works

Comment: @Simon no it does not. `default` equals to null. And `default(KeyValuePair<T,U>)` is an actual KeyValuePair that contains `null, null`. Experienced this myself.

Comment: Backing @Simon here. My KVP type is `KeyValuePair<int,string>`. The default value returned by `keyValueList.SingleOrDefault()` contains `0,null`. When I do `getResult.Equals(default)`, it returns `true`. Tested in net framework 4.7.2.

Comment: I have just checked this with .net core 5 and getResult.Equals(default) will return false when getResult.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<T,U>)) returns true.

Answer (score 118):

You can create a general (and generic) extension method, like this one:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsDefault<T>(this T value) where T : struct
    {
        bool isDefault = value.Equals(default(T));

        return isDefault;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// We have to set explicit default value '0' to avoid build error:
// Use of unassigned local variable 'intValue'
int intValue = 0;
long longValue = 12;
KeyValuePair<String, int> kvp1 = new KeyValuePair<String, int>("string", 11);
KeyValuePair<String, int> kvp2 = new KeyValuePair<String, int>();
List<KeyValuePair<String, int>> kvps = new List<KeyValuePair<String, int>> { kvp1, kvp2 };
KeyValuePair<String, int> kvp3 = kvps.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == 11);
KeyValuePair<String, int> kvp4 = kvps.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == 15);

Console.WriteLine(intValue.IsDefault()); // results 'True'
Console.WriteLine(longValue.IsDefault()); // results 'False'
Console.WriteLine(kvp1.IsDefault()); // results 'False'
Console.WriteLine(kvp2.IsDefault()); // results 'True'
Console.WriteLine(kvp3.IsDefault()); // results 'False'
Console.WriteLine(kvp4.IsDefault()); // results 'True'
```

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
KeyValuePair<string,int> current = this.recent.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Key.Equals(dialog.FileName) == true);

if (current.Key == null)
    this.recent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>(dialog.FileName,0));
```

Comment: Of course, that only works if you're never going to (accidentally or purposefully) add null as a key. But I'd say that's true the vast majority of the time, so good idea. That is definitely a way simpler check than most of the checks here.

Comment: As long as the key is nullable.

Answer (score 10):

```
if(getResult.Key.Equals(default(T)) && getResult.Value.Equals(default(U)))
```

Comment: The only thing is that is doesn't compile. Equals should be used instead.

Answer (score 9):

From your original code it looks like what you want is to check if the list was empty:

```
var getResult= keyValueList.SingleOrDefault();
if (keyValueList.Count == 0)
{
   /* default */
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: You can just omit the first line, as it's not used.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend more understanding way using extension method:

```
public static class KeyValuePairExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull<T, TU>(this KeyValuePair<T, TU> pair)
    {
        return pair.Equals(new KeyValuePair<T, TU>());
    }
}
```

And then just use:

```
var countries = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"cz", "prague"},
    {"de", "berlin"}
};

var country = countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "en");

if(country.IsNull()){

}
```

Answer (score 8):

To avoid the boxing of `KeyValuePair.Equals(object)` you can use a `ValueTuple`.

```cs
if ((getResult.Key, getResult.Value) == default)
```

Answer (score 2):

It may suffice, for your application, to check if either the Key, or the Value are `default`.. For example if you have a `KeyValuePair<int,string>` mapping positive nonzero integers to strings, and the strings are never null, then either:

```
if(getResult.Key == default)

if(getResult.Value == default)
```

Would be an indicator that a default KVP has been returned

In essence, there may be no need to test the whole KVP for being default, if just one test will do; consider it for your use case

Answer (score 0):

using pattern match in `C# 8.0` or above or `.NET Core 3.x`, `.NET 5.x` or above

```cs
//
// assume key is string and value is object
//

var getResult = keyValueList.SingleOrDefault();

// if clause
if (getResult is { Key: default(string), Value: default(object) })
{
    do_both_key_value_are_default();
}
// if clause negate
if (getResult is not { Key: default(string), Value: default(object) })
{
    do_both_key_value_found();
}


// switch style
switch (getResult)
{
    case { Key: default(string), Value: default(object) }: // this is default case where cannot find the single
        do_both_key_value_are_default();
        break;
    default:
        do_something_else();
        break;
}
```