# KeyValuePair Is Nothing

Tags: .net

How can we verify (.NET 2) if a `KeyValuePair` has a value assigned or not?

```
Dim pair as KeyValuePair(Of A, B) = Nothing

if pair.??? Then Return
```

As is it a structure, it **can't** be verified with `pair Is Nothing`.

**Point** structure, by eg. has a **`p.IsEmpty`** verification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than using the "normal" type here - which means you can't detect the difference between a value with the default values of `A` and `B` as the key and value, you should use a `Nullable(Of KeyValuePair(Of A, B))`.

Effectively you're asking *exactly* the same question as asking whether an `Integer` variable has a value, where setting it to `Nothing` would give it a value of 0. How can you tell the difference between that 0 and a "real" 0? You can't - which is why `Nullable(Of T)` exists in the first place. The exact same logic applies to `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: So, you confirm that for that structure .NET does not provide a "empty detection" mechanism like it does for the Point?.. Because `Point = Nothing === Point.IsEmpty`

Comment: @serhio: there's no general mechanism like that, no.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of a nullable type, you can compare it to an empty KeyValuePair:

```
If pair.Equals(New KeyValuePair(Of A, B)) Then Return
```

See the C# answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641405/151325

Comment: In some cases, such as when using Linq via `.SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`, you do not get the chance to deal with `Nullable(Of KeyValuePair(Of A, B))`. As opposed to the accepted answer for this particular case, this answer does work and seems pretty safe to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `Nullable(Of T)` type is for. Prior to the introduction of generics in .NET 2.0 (which made this type possible), any value type that wished to expose a semantic "empty" value had to do so on its own. This was usually presented by the structure using a "reserved value" to represent "empty", as you see with `Point`, where any `Point` at `(0, 0)` is considered to be "empty". There is no way to distinguish between a `Point` that is empty and a `Point` that represents the origin. Other ways were contrived to represent emtpy values by using a boolean flag, but the way that these types were used was unintuitive (in that the consuming code still had a value in the variable).

Rather than force every value type that wished to support the concept of an empty or null value, the `Nullable(Of T)` type was introduced. This essentially took the latter (i.e. boolean flag) concept and made it available for each and every value type, both system and user-defined. It also allows comparisons between a `Nullable(Of T)` and `Nothing` (`null` in C#) to check for the presence of a value.

One thing that should be made clear, however, is that (as a value type itself), the `Nullable(Of T)` structure is never actually a null reference; the ability to compare it against `Nothing` is purely a language feature that's present both in VB.NET and C#. Under the covers, all such comparisons are actually checking the `HasValue` property on the structure. Additionally, accessing the `Value` property of the structure throws an exception if `HasValue` is false.

Comment: For the performance POW, are the Nullable types much less perfromant that its "normal" structures with a flag?

Comment: @serhio: No; while generics do technically introduce some overhead, it is not substantial.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old, but for a basic solution:

```
Dim pair as New KeyValuePair(Of A, B)(Nothing, Nothing)
'...'
'<some code that may or may not set pair to KeyValuePair(Of A, B)(Something, Something)>'
'...'
if pair.Key = Nothing Then Return ' some code did not fire
```

In this case either `A` or `B` would need to be compatible with `= Nothing` or `Is Nothing`.