# Instantiation followed by assignment compiles, but

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, reference

I want to allow the user, when searching for a Platypus, to enter either the Platypus' ID or Name (or portion of a name).

The database is down right now, so I can't test this code, but the fact that I'm assigning to kvp twice doesn't seem right. Anyway, first my code:

```
String SearchVal = textBoxPlatypusNumOrPartialName.Text.Trim();
int PlatypusID;
int.TryParse(SearchVal, out PlatypusID);

Dictionary<int, string> CandidatePlatypusDict = PlatypusID > 0 ? PlatypusSetupData.GetPlatypusById(PlatypusID) :        PlatypusSetupData.GetCandidatePlatypusFromName(SearchVal);

KeyValuePair<int, String> kvp = new KeyValuePair<int, string>();
using (var getPlatypusIDAndNameDlg = new GetPlatypusForm(CandidatePlatypusDict)) {
    DialogResult dr = getPlatypusIDAndNameDlg.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == DialogResult.OK) {
        kvp = getPlatypusIDAndNameDlg.PlatypusKVP; 
    }
}
```

...Now, if I try this instead:

```
KeyValuePair<int, String> kvp; // = new KeyValuePair<int, string>();
```

I get: "Use of unassigned local variable 'kvp'"

And I can't assign null as KeyValuePair, as it is a non-nullable type.

Is this instantiation of kvp followed by assignment to it okay, and if not, how can I work around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The default for KeyValuePair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641392/the-default-for-keyvaluepair)

Comment: Out of interest, why use keyvaluepair for search results? Could you not have a List<IPlatypus> instead for example? It simplifies many of these kind of problems as you only deal with Platypus' then - which is what you are searching for. I've really enjoyed these questions of yours!

Comment: @-: Thanks, but why (have you enjoyed them)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this instantiation of kvp followed by assignment to it okay, and if not, how can I work around it?

Well it's *okay* - but you might instead want:

```
KeyValuePair<int, String> kvp;
using (...) {
   kvp = dr == DialogResult.OK ? getPlatypusIDAndNameDlg.PlatypusKVP 
                               : /* some other value here */;
}
```

That way it's clearly only assigned once, but is *always* assigned. Next you need to work out what value you *want* it to have in the situation where `dr` isn't `DialogResult.OK`.

Answer (score 1):

If it makes sense for your KeyValuePair to be null, then declare it as nullable:

```
KeyValuePair<int, String>? kvp = null;
```

But be sure you use the nullability (it's totally a word) correctly later in your code.

Edit:

Make use of the properties that it will now have like

```
kvp.HasValue;
kvp.Value;
```

and the method

kvp.GetValueOrDefault();