# What is default value of `KeyValuePair<string, int>`?

Tags: c#, linq

What is default value of `KeyValuePair<string, int>`?

e.g. I am running a LINQ query and returning `FirstOrDefault()` value from it

```
KeyValuePair<string, int> mapping = (from p in lstMappings
    where p.Key.Equals(dc.ColumnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    select p).FirstOrDefault();

if (mapping != null)
{ 

}
```

how to check if `mapping` object is null/blank
(I am getting compile time error in above code `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>' and '<null>'`)

PS: `lstMappings` is of type

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
```

Comment: That's very poor use of a LINQ query. You shouldn't be using LINQ at all there. If you want to be able treat your keys in a case-insensitive manner the you should be providing your own IEqualityComparer that will do just that. You would then simply use the ContainsKey method of the Dictionary to determine whether there's a match and, if there is, get the value by that key.

Comment: duplicate of [The default for KeyValuePair](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641392/3834)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The default value of any type T is [`default(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.120).aspx), so for 100% theoretical accuracy you would write

```
if (!mapping.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, int>))) {
    // ...
}
```

Since `KeyValuePair` is a `struct` (i.e. a value type) you cannot compare it to `null`. Irrespective of that, comparing values with `==` is wrong as a default approach because if used on reference types it normally checks for reference equality.

Comment: "comparing values with `==` is wrong as a default approach because if used on reference types it normally checks for reference equality" ??? I think it's quite standard practice?

Answer (score 24):

[`KeyValuePair<T, T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) is a struct. As such, it is a value type, cannot be `null`, and will be initialized with the member’s default values.

For `KeyValuePair<string, int>`, this will be the `null` string, and the int value `0`.

```
KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp = default(KeyValuePair<string, int>);
Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key == null); // True
Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value == 0); // True
```

Just like I used `default(T)` to intialize the object with its default value, you can also use it to compare your result with it to find out if it’s the default value or not:

```
if (!mapping.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, int>)))
{ … }
```

The other alternative, if you don’t want to work with the default value anyway, would be to just use `First` and check for the exception which is thrown when there isn’t a result value.

Comment: Using your example of comparing to the default, I get `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>' and 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>'`. Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 5):

`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a structure, therefore a value type and cannot be `null`. Default value of a struct is stuct populated with default values of it's members. In this example it would be:

> new KeyValuePair(null, 0)

---

That should answer your direct question, but a more elegant way to do comparison you are trying to do is to use [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword.

```
if (mapping != default(KeyValuePair<string, int>))
{ 
    // Mapping has default value
}
```

You could use equivalent code for any other type beside `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. For reference types `default` will return `null`, otherwise it will return default value of value type.

Comment: The default value of a string is null, not the empty string.