# A 2-in-1 check existence and store - is this possible when searching a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, value-type

A common pattern I like to use in C# is one where instead of first checking whether something exists in a collection with `Any` then finding it again with `First`, I simply call `FirstOrDefault`, which both tells me whether it exists and if so, gives me a reference to it:

```
List<Person> people = ...;
Person found;
if ((found = people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Age > 10)) != null) {
    // Found person with age over 10, and we have them in 'found'
    //...
}
```

This works when the thing being found is a reference type, and can be null.  However, I was trying to do the same thing with a `Dictionary`'s entries:

```
Dictionary<(int X, int Y), ITileData<(int X, int Y)>> srchField = new();
KeyValuePair<(int X, int Y), ITileData<(int X, int Y)>> next;
while ((next = srchField.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.Value.Reached)) != null) {
    // Found next, and we have it in 'next'
    //...
}
```

This, however, doesn't work because `srchField.FirstOrDefault(...)` returns a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, which is a struct.  I can work around this by first calling `Any` on `srchField`, and then calling `First` with the same predicate if `Any` finds anything, but this is having to do the same search twice.  Is there any way I can do the 2-in-1 check existence and store here, only carrying out one search of the dictionary in LINQ?

Comment: Related: [Check if KeyValuePair exists with LINQ's FirstOrDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793897/check-if-keyvaluepair-exists-with-linqs-firstordefault). Pay attention to [Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/793936/11178549)'s answer (the `TryGetFirst` extension method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @TheodorZoulias pointing me in the right direction, and inspired by a combination of the answer from @Samuel and the nice code solution from @JonSkeet (I hadn't actually realized that if LINQ `.Take(1)` only finds 0 elements, it actually gives you an enumerable of 0 instead of throwing an exception), I came up with an extension method that works well for doing this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions {
    public static bool TryGetFirst<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate, out TSource first) {
        if (predicate == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
        }

        var query = source.Where(predicate).Take(1).ToList();
        if (query.Count == 0) {
            first = default;
            return false;
        }
        first = query[0];
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
while (srchField.TryGetFirst(x => !x.Value.Reached, out KeyValuePair<(int X, int Y), ITileData<(int X, int Y)>> next)) {
    var key = next.Key;
    var val = next.Value;
    // ... use eg. key.X, key.Y, and val ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `while (d.TryGetFirst` end up being an endless loop if it finds anything (assuming you don't modify the dictionary in the body, of course)?

Comment: Yes it would.  I pulled this example usage from my code where I... modify the dictionary in the body.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the key in your search and your values are reference types, you can just use `Values` properties of a dictionary:

```
srchField.Values.FirstOrDefault(!v => v.Reached)
```

If you want to do something with keys, it would be a bit more clunky:

```
srchField.Where(kvp => Predicate(kvp.Key)).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: But that still selects the `Value` at the end, right?  I wouldn't have access to the key.  And yeah I do need the key.

Comment: Would wrapping a struct into a `Nullable` be an option?