# Why can TimeSpan and Guid Structs be compared to null?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, null, struct

I've noticed that some .NET structs can be compared to null.
For example:

```
  TimeSpan y = new TimeSpan();
        if (y == null)
            return;
```

will compile just fine (the same with the Guid struct).
Now I know that stucts are value type and that the code above should not compile, unless there's an overload of operator == which takes an object. But, as far as I could tell there isn't.
I've looked at the class with Reflector, and also at the docs on MSDN.
The two of them do implement the following interfaces:

```
IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
```

but, trying to implment the same Interfaces did not seem to help:

```
struct XX : IComparable, IComparable<XX>, IEquatable<XX> {
    public int CompareTo(Object obj) {
        return 0;
    }
    public int CompareTo (XX other){
        return 0;
    }
    public bool Equals (XX other){
        return false;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object value){
        return false;
    }
    public static int Compare(XX t1, XX t2){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm using: .NET 2.0 Visual Studio 2005.

Does anyone has any idea what's the reason for this ?
I am just trying to get a better understanding. This isn't an issue as I know I shouldn't compare structs to null anyway.

Comment: "I'm using: .NET 2.0 Visual Studio 2005." - does it raise a warning? IIRC, it should do in 2005 (but not 2008, see below)

Comment: No warning for TimeSpan
there's an error for XX:
 error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TransControl.TraceDisplay.XX' and '<null>'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an object not be compared to null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648115/how-can-an-object-not-be-compared-to-null)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the `==` operator.

The `TimeSpan` class has an overload of the equality operator:

```
public static bool operator ==(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
     return (t1._ticks == t2._ticks);
}
```

This in itself doesn't make it possible to compare with `null`, **but**...

With the arrival of nullable types, **each struct is implicitly convertible to its nullable type**, so when you see something like

```
TimeSpan y = new TimeSpan();
if (y == null)
    return;
```

You *don't see* that this is happening:

```
TimeSpan y = new TimeSpan();
if ((Nullable<TimeSpan>)y == (Nullable<TimeSpan>)null)
    return;
```

Null gets the implicit conversion (implicit assignment?), but *not all `System.Object` objects* do:

```
TimeSpan y = new TimeSpan();
object o = null;
if (y == o) //compiler error
    return;
```

Okay, but the equality operator doesn't take nullable arguments, does it?

Well, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) is of help here, stating:

> The predefined unary and binary
>   operators and any user-defined
>   operators that exist for value types
>   may also be used by nullable types.
>   These operators produce a null value
>   if [any of] the operands are null; otherwise,
>   the operator uses the contained value
>   to calculate the result.

So you effectively get **a nullable implementation for each operator for free**, with a fixed defined behaviour. The "contained value" mentioned above is the actual value the non-nullable operator would return.

Comment: You are right ! it's the operator== !
Adding it to my custom struct will now allow me to compare to null!

Comment: Yep. Maybe I should have added that sentence to the start of my post for clarity :)

Answer (score 7):

This case is covered for generics in section 7.9.6 of the C# language specification.

> The x == null construct is permitted even though T could represent a value type, and the result is simply defined to be false when T is a value type.

I dug through the spec for a bit and couldn't find a more general rule.  Jon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225949/why-can-timespan-and-guid-structs-be-compared-to-null/1226003#1226003) indicates it's a nullable promotion issue.

This rule (or a similar variation) does seem to be being applied here.  If you look at the reflected output closely you'll notice the comparison isn't there.  The C# compiler is apparently optimizing this comparison away and replacing it with false.

For instance, if you type the following

```
var x = new TimeSpan();
var y = x == null;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Then decompile it you'll see the following

```
var x = new TimeSpan();
var y = false;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: In fact, the compiler should issue a warning here, if it replaces the comparison. At least, it does in other circumstances. Mysterious.

Comment: It's also interesting that if you put it into a comparison ... if( x == null) you will get a warning for an int type, but not for a guid type.  Maybe there is a secret way to null out a Guid. :)

Comment: Custom structs covered by the connect issue I posted.

Answer (score 7):

This problem was effectively introduced when nullable types were included. There's an implicit conversion from `TimeSpan` to `TimeSpan?`, and there's a comparison between `TimeSpan?` and the null value of that type.

The compiler issues a warning for some types which makes it clearer what it's trying to do:

```
int x = 10;
if (x == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Gives this warning:

```
Test.cs(9,13): warning CS0472: The result of the expression is always 'false'
       since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'
```

I believe Marc Gravell and I worked out the circumstances under which the warning is given once... it's a shame it's not consistent.

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it ;-p For any custom struct (was it with Equals? ==?) it will **silently** (without warning) notice that it is redundant. IIRC it changed between C# 2.0 and C# 3.0; care to try C# 4.0? It may have been re-fixed...

Comment: @Marc, I tried the OP's repro on VS2010 Beta1 and it repros.  Didn't try many other cases

Comment: @JaredPar - yes, when I found the connect issue I posted, Ed Maurer said he wasn't going to fix it. Sorry, my 2010 comment pre-dated me finding the article ;-p

Comment: Surely there's someone here we can blame this on :deal:

Comment: @Marc- I've looked up your connect issue:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=348850
I thought it might be benefit others.
Ed Maurer says there used to be a warning in previous versions, but as I mentioned I am not getting one in VS2005

Answer (score 4):

See also: [C# 3 (.NET 3.5) version of csc fails to report CS0162 for unrechable code (struct/null)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=348850)

Starting with the C# 3 compiler that means it sometimes doesn't even warn you about this ;-p

Because `Guid` / `TimeSpan` etc provide `==`, they fall into this trap where it doesn't warn you.

Answer (score 3):

**I FOUND IT** :)

The following gives a warning:

```
int i = 0;
if (i == null)
// ^^ Warning: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of
//             type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'
```

The compiler is just failing to emit the correct warning that the `null` you typed was converted to type `TimeSpan?` for the comparison.

Edit: The related section in the spec is §13.7.1 stating that `null` can be implicitly converted to any nullable type, and (the very difficult to read) section §13.7.2 stating a value type `T` can be implicitly converted to `T?`.

What I originally wrote:

Whatever's happening is something in the C# spec because like JaredPar says it compiles to simply `false`.

Note that this doesn't compile:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
object o = null;
if (ts == o) // error, Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'object'
    ...
```