# Why am I allowed to compare a non-nullable type with null?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, non-nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# okay with comparing value types to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null)

If I try to assign `null` to a non-nullable type in C#:

```
System.DateTime time = null;
```

I'll get a compile-time error:

> error CS0037: Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type

which makes sense. But if compare the same type against `null`:

```
System.DateTime time = obtainFromSomewhere();
if( time == null ) {
    //whatever;
}
```

there's no compile-time error. This doesn't make sense to me - if I can't assign `null` then why would it ever be `null`?

Why am I allowed to compare a non-nullable type with `null`?

Comment: Because the statement itself is valid. You can always check an object for null.

Comment: Isn't it valid because of allowed implicit convertion of non-nullable types to nullabe?

Comment: See [Comparing structs to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022425/comparing-structs-to-null) and [C# okay with comparing value types to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null) where Eric Lippert already provided an excellent answer (so far none of the answers here seems correct).

Comment: @0xA3: Brian's answer is essentially correct, but yes, you are correct in that this is a duplicate.  @sharptooth: if you compare a built-in type like int to null, the compiler gives a warning that the comparison is always false, but does not do so for lifted user-defined equality operators; this is a shortcoming of the compiler. I apologize for the lack of a warning; we really should add one here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason this works for `DateTime`, is because `DateTime` defines it own `==` operator. Because it does so, it gets a lifted version of the operator which may be used with `DateTime?`. Since both `DateTime` and `null` may be implicitly converted to `DateTime?`, the comparison compiles but will always evaluate to false at runtime.

Thanks to Matt Ellen for pointing out the fact that my original answer didn't cover the example in the question.

Comment: but In sharptooth's example, there is no type parameter, so it should not compile. A compile time error should occur unless both operands are reference-types or `null`.

Comment: In fact just above your quote is this: "The predefined reference type equality operators do not permit value type operands to be compared. Therefore, unless a struct type declares its own equality operators, it is not possible to compare values of that struct type."

Answer (score 5):

It's due to [Boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

`DateTime` can be *boxed* as `object` and thus it becomes a reference which can be compared with `null` (though it will always be `false`).

However, an object (`null`) can't be *unboxed* back to `DateTime`, thus it can't be assigned to `DateTime`.

Example:
you could do

```
object now = DateTime.Now;
bool isNull = now == null
```

**EDIT:**
As Brian Rasmussen pointed out, I was wrong with the boxing theory. Boxing would only occur if explicitly casted to object like in my example or in `(object)DateTime.Now == null`.

Comment: He should use DataTime? instead of DateTime! this is a common practice

Comment: @Farzin Zaker: the question asked here is "Why am I allowed to compare a non-nullable type with null?" not "What should I use".

Comment: There is *no* boxing. Check the generated IL.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: you're right.

Comment: It is **not** due to boxing. The C# 4.0 specification section 7.6.10 states "**The predefined reference type equality operators never cause boxing operations to occur for their operands.**"

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit conversion to a nullable type since .NET 2.0 (See what Eric Lippert said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null)).

The compiler gives you the following warning that indicates that a conversion takes place:

```
C:\>c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc test.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler version 8.00.50727.4927
for Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 2005 Framework version 2.0.50727

test.cs(16,12): warning CS0464: Comparing with null of type 'int?' always produces 'false'
```

In .NET 1.1 which didn't have nullable types your code sample would not have been legal:

```
C:\>c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\csc test.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# .NET Compiler version 7.10.3052.4
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 1.1.4322
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2001-2002. All rights reserved.

test.cs(12,13): error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and ''
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be a nullable type :

```
System.DateTime? time = null;
```

your code should appear like this :

```
System.DateTime? time = obtainFromSomewhere();
if( time.HasValue ) {
    //use time.Value;
}
```

but remember your `obtainFromSomewhere` function should return a `DateTime?` type.

Comment: Em.. Shouldn't it be `if( time.HasValue )`?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking. If `null` was obtained, how can we "use" `.Value`?

Comment: "If time doesn't have a value, use time's value..."???

Comment: no, you should check the HasValue property if was true, then use Value property.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is allowed, because NULL is not a real value from no type.

It is good some code like below is allowed :

```
System.DateTime time = obtainFromSomewhere(); // allways a date
System.DateTime? otherTime = obtainFromSomewhereElse(); // null if nothing planned

if (time == otherTime)
{
    // match
    ...
}
```

[What would we do without null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393341/what-would-we-do-without-null) anyway ?