# How does the C# visual studio compiler treat struct/NULL comparisons?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, struct, null, compile-time-constant

We just ran across some bad code like this in our c#.net 4 codebase

```
DateTime myDate = someValue;
If (myDate==Null)
    Do Something
```

It occurred to us that this condition will never occur.

How does the compiler handle these non-nullable struct comparisons?

Originally we were surprised that it would compile... but rationalized it on the point that you could certainly have a constant comparison like:

```
If(1==2)
```

Which would also never resolve true... but in that case the compiler can easily tell they are constants. Does it optimize or rollup non-nullable comparisons?

Comment: Which language is this? What do you mean by ".NET compiler"?

Comment: This is a: language dependent, and b: compiler-dependent (heuristic code removal is usuallt an optimisation - in fact it changed between different MS c# versions, and depends on what operators are defined!)

Comment: @JohnSaunders C# in Vis Studio. Sorry for the ambiguity. Edited.

Comment: Hmm, something a-miss here.  I don't see what implicit conversion could prevent the compiler from generating an error.

Comment: @HansPassant: `(Nullable<DateTime>)myDate ==(Nullable<DateTime>)null` works, but only if `myDate` has implemented the `==` operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I punched this into LinqPad:

```
var t = new DateTime();
t.Dump();
(t == null).Dump();
```

And got this:

```
IL_0000:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0002:  initobj     System.DateTime
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     
IL_0009:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
IL_000E:  pop         
IL_000F:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0010:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
```

So yes, the compiler compiles it to the same as:

```
var t = new DateTime();
t.Dump();
(false).Dump();
```

Interestingly, if I create my own struct (`TestStruct`) and try this:

```
TestStruct t;
(t == null).Dump();
```

... the compiler complains that I can't do an equals comparison between `TestSruct` and `null`.

#### Update

In a comment, Paolo points to another StackOverflow post reporting this last phenomenon. Apparently by overloading the `==` and `!=` operators, a value type becomes subject to an automatic conversion from `t == null` to `(Nullable<TestClass>)t == (Nullable<TestClass>)null`. If you haven't overloaded those operators, this implicit conversion doesn't make sense, so you get an error.

Comment: +1 I really need to learn to use LinqPad

Comment: I think you mean that the compiler complains that you can't do an equals comparison between TestStruct and null.

Comment: Check out this answer if you want to know why your second case is not compiling http://stackoverflow.com/a/2022669/63011