# Why is there no compiler error when I test for a datetime null and a compiler error when I pass a null to a method that expects a DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have a constructor like this:

```
public MyClass(DateTime dateOfBirth, decimal cost)
{
    DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    Cost = cost;
}
```

I need to add some validation.  Do I need to check if these variables are null?

1) If I attempt to do this for cost, then there is a compiler warning saying that a decimal is never null:

```
if(cost==null) { }
```

2) If I attempt to do this for dateOfBirth, then there is no problem:

```
if(dateOfBirth==null) { }
```

3) If I attempt to do this for dateOfBirth, then there are two compiler errors (one for each variable):

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass(null, null);
```

Why is there no compiler error when I test for a DateTime null and a compiler error when I pass a null to a method that expects a DateTime? What validation do I need to do here for nulls?

Comment: @Win I think the question is more about why the `DateTime` `ValueType` doesn't have the compiler warning that `ValueType`s like `Decimal` have when checking for null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing structs to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022425/comparing-structs-to-null)

Comment: @Jonathon Chase, thanks.  That is what I am getting at.  Can you answer?

Comment: @w0051977 Tools like ReSharper (and by extension, Rider) will mark checks of non-nullable types against null as Always true or Always false depending on the circumstance. I am unsure why the compiler warning was implemented for some structs and not others.

Comment: @Jonathon Chase, I guess it is pointless checking for null inside the constructor?

Comment: @w0051977 If the parameter is a value-type that isn't marked Nullable<T> (ie declared `DateTime? whatever` or `Nullable<DateTime> whatever`) then you can safely assume that it will not be null in your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `decimal` and `System.DateTime` are value types. This means (unless you declare them as nullable - `decimal?` or `DateTime?`) they cannot have a `null` value.

So, it would be pointless to check whether they are `null`, since they cannot have a `null` value. Similarly, it is pointless to pass `null` for these data types in a constructor or method parameter.

> As for whether to make them nullable vs use a logical default (`DateTime.MaxValue` or `decimal.MinValue`, for example) is a design choice you will need to make yourself.

And as for why the compiler doesn't complain when you check `DateTime` for `null`, I can't really say for sure - that sounds like a compiler bug. But since most developers are not in the habit of checking value types for `null`, it is not a major cause for concern.

Comment: @NightOwl888: It may be _pointless_ to test equality with `null` for a value type, but it is not invalid. The code will compile.

Comment: I think OP is also wondering why he's getting a compiler warning for comparing decimal to `null` but not when comparing DateTime to `null`.

Comment: Both comparing decimal and DateTime to null is pointless because the expression will always be false