# How do I detect if a Guid? is in a List<Guid?>

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, lambda, guid, nullable

With the following code:

```
Guid? x = null;
List<Guid?> y = new List<Guid?>();
y.Add(x);
```

I would expect the following code to return true `y.Contains(x);` but it returns false.

So this is sort of a two part question.

1. Why does it return false when clearly there x in the list?
2. How would I loop through a Guid? List to check if a null `Guid?` or `Guid?` with value is in the list?

Comment: You need to post better repro code, it works fine with the syntax mistakes removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's examine your code. What it really says without the syntactic sugar is:

```
Nullable<Guid> x = new Nullable<Guid>(new Guid());
List<Nullable<Guid>> y = new List<Nullable<Guid>>();
y.Add(x);
```

#### Explanation

`Nullable<>` is actually a `struct`, so it's not really ever `null`; only its `Value` property has a chance of being `null`, but since its underlying type (`Guid`) is *also* a `struct`, **nothing** in your list is ever *really* `null`.

So why did I explain that? Well, when it comes time for `List<>.Contains()` to do its magic, the conditions of the combination of the two `struct`'s `Equals()` methods are determining that your empty `Guid`s don't equal.

> The nullable equality operator that takes two nullable guids is applicable in this situation, will be called, and will always return false.

*[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177971/74757)*

#### How do we fix it?

Since having `Nullable` in your solution is pretty useless, I would refactor your code to get rid of it. `Guid` instead has a handy-dandy `Empty` property we can use instead:

```
Guid x = Guid.Empty;
List<Guid> y = new List<Guid>();
y.Add(x);

Console.WriteLine(y.Contains(x)); // True
Console.WriteLine(y.Contains(Guid.Empty)); // True
```

See the above in action: **[Ideone](http://ideone.com/lEMYM)**

Again, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177850/guid-null-should-not-be-allowed-by-the-compiler) from Eric Lippert for more information.

#### Update:

If you're looking for all `null` (or Empty) items in the list, perhaps it would make more sense to check for items `x` in the list where `x.HasValue` is `false`:

```
var myList = new List<Guid>();
... /* add to myList */
var theEmpties = myList.Where(x => x == Guid.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you forgot () near `new List<Guid?>`. So your code works fine and `y.Contains(x)` returns true.
My code for check Guid in `List<Guid?>`:

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
foreach (var elem in y)
{
    if (elem != null && guid == elem.Value)
    {
        //CODE
    }
}
```