# Null check value types passed via parameters

Tags: c#, .net, value-type

Considering that value types are always initalised by default and never null would it be worth to null check value types passed in to methods via parameters?

E.g. is it worth performing the following check

```
public void Method(Guid x)
{
  if (x == null)
   throw new ArgumentNullException();
...
}
```

Comment: You can't compare value types to null. You'll get a compiler error. What you can do instead is compare it to `default(Guid)`. It's a similar check, but `default(type)` is usually a valid value as well (e.g. `default(int)` is 0), so you need to be careful.

Comment: What's the point of null-checking something that can never be null? Is there some other question behind this one?

Comment: @Venky it's *already* a Guid, what is there to validate? `Parse` and `TryParse` are used to convert *strings* to Guids

Comment: @itsme86: Interestingly, for `Guid`s anyway, you don't get a compiler error.

Comment: @sstan See this question for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177850/guid-null-should-not-be-allowed-by-the-compiler

Comment: @itsme86, this will compile just fine.  Hopefully the compiler is smart enough to toss the code in release mode but their is nothing wrong with checking is a guid is equal to null.  (it will always be false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the condition is technically *valid* (because of operator overload rules and nullable types), it can only ever evaluate to `false`. That's why, in some cases, you will get a compiler warning to let you know that the only possible outcome is `false`.

So, unless there is more to your question, it comes down to asking if this code is worth it:

```
public void Method(Guid x)
{
  if (false)
   throw new ArgumentNullException();
...
}
```

The answer should be pretty obvious.