# Can a C# Guid be null?

Tags: c#, guid

I know there is a such a thing as `Guid?` and `Nullable<Guid>`. I have this code and it compiles:

```
public Contact GetContact(Guid contactId)
{
    if (contactId == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contactId));
    }

    return _communicationsDbContext.Set<Contact>().Find(contactId);
}
```

Can "contactId == null" ever be true?

Comment: No, it cannot. In fact, when you compile you get a warning telling you so

Comment: By the way, `Guid?` is a shorthand to `Nullable<Guid>`

Comment: What happened when you tried to set `contactId = null;`?

Comment: I tried what Gnbrkm41 said. The compiler just removes that line of code.

Comment: I am asking if a Guid can ever be null? (I am not asking how to make it nullable). The reason I am asking is because the compiler isn't complaining about the code.

Comment: `I am asking if a Guid can ever be null?` The answer is No (as shown in the duplicate). `The reason I am asking is because the compiler isn't complaining about the code.` Well, I can't ever be George Clooney - but that doesn't mean you can't **ask** whether I am George Clooney. `if (contactId == null)` is technically valid code. It is silly (since it will never be `true`). But it is not invalid. Which is why it compiles for you.

Comment: Reason `if (contactId == null)` compiles is because Guid implements custom equality operator (`public static bool operator == (Guid left, object right)`). Operator too is a method; think of it as `Guid.op_Equality(contactId, (object)null)`. `struct`s do not implement a default equality operator, so for `struct`s that do not implement custom == would not compile as there's no such method.

Comment: One reason someone might implement equality operator that returns true when compared with null could be to write their own Nullable<T>. Nullable<T> is a struct, therefore it cannot be null; but it can be compared to null and returns true if the object represents null. (Though I don't know why someone would do it if there's already a built-in type with syntactic sugar)

Comment: Side note: comparison between Nullable<T> instance and null gets substituted to property call nullable.HasValue in compile time. It's more of a language feature rather than custom equality operator; Nullable<> does not implement equality operator.

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177850/guid-null-should-not-be-allowed-by-the-compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Guid is a struct, which cannot be null as it is not a reference type. I believe that for known `struct` types that implement custom equality operator (e.g. int, Guid etc) the compiler will substitute the null comparison with false. (Hence the whole comparison and throw statement will disappear)

For the `struct` types that do not implement custom equality operator, the code simply won't compile.

Nonetheless, it is unnecessary.

See: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgcBmIgJgIGECBvKgzounAFgICyACgDiAVzQATAgHMJkgJRsOXVWgBmBIXKkEAvHoIA7MRgxKYACwQB7AO7G4DgIII5YOEZgA5UxgCiAB4AxnAADjBoNkZCChSUqgC+VIlAA===

```cs
public void M(Guid guid)
{
    if (guid == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

will be compiled to:

```
// Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M (
            valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid guid
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 1 (0x1)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ret
    } // end of method C::M
```

As you can see, the first instruction in the method is return.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Guid` is a `struct`, and structs can never be `null`.

Instead, you may wish to check that it is not the "zero" Guid:

```
x != Guid.Empty
```

Answer (score 1):

A Guid is a value type so it can't be null. One way to check is:

```
if (contactId == Guid.Empty)
```

or

```
 contactId == default(Guid)
```