# Creating 'good' hash codes for .NET ala Boost.Functional/Hash

Tags: c#, .net, hash

For C++ I've always been using [Boost.Functional/Hash](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/hash.html) to create good hash values without having to deal with bit shifts, XORs and prime numbers. Is there any libraries that produces good (I'm not asking for optimal) hash values for C#/.NET? I would use this utility to implement GetHashCode(), not cryptographic hashes.

To clarify why I think this is useful, here's the implementation of `boost::hash_combine` which combines to hash values (ofcourse a very common operation when implementing GetHashCode()):

```
seed ^= hash_value(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
```

Clearly, this sort of code doesn't belong in the implementation of `GetHashCode()` and should therefor be implemented elsewhere.

Comment: How do you define good hashes? For what purpose? And why don't you like `GetHashCode()`?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the OP. He wants to have something like Boost.Functional/Hash *to use it inside `GetHashCode`*!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I like GetHashCode(), I just want a better way to implement it. Most developers end up just doing `_member1.GetHashCode() + _member2.GetHashCode()` etc.

Comment: "Clearly, this sort of code doesn't belong in the implementation of `GetHashCode()`": I don't see any reason why not unless you are writing a lot of such merges then move to a helper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) contains some examples of helper-classes that resembles Boost.Functional/Hash. None looks quite as elegant, though.

I am not aware of any real .NET library that provides the equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't used a separate library just for that. As mentioned before, for the `GetHashCode` method it is essential to be fast and stable. Usually I prefer to write inline implementation, but it might be actually a good idea to use a helper class:

```
internal static class HashHelper
{
    private static int InitialHash = 17; // Prime number
    private static int Multiplier = 23; // Different prime number

    public static Int32 GetHashCode(params object[] values)
    {
        unchecked // overflow is fine
        {
            int hash = InitialHash;

            if (values != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    object currentValue = values[i];
                    hash = hash * Multiplier
                        + (currentValue != null ? currentValue.GetHashCode() : 0);
                }

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

This way common hash-calculation logic can be used:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return HashHelper.GetHashCode(field1, field2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have very specific requirements you don't need to calculate your type's hashcode from first principles. Rather combine the hash codes of the fields/properties you use for equality determination in one of the simple ways, something like:

```
int hash = field1.GetHashCode();
hash = (hash *37) + field2.GetHashCode();
```

(Combination function taken from §3.3.2 [*C# in Depth*, 2<sup>nd</sup> Ed, Jon Skeet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471)).

Comment: Use 31 not 37. 37 can lead to degenerate hashes because Dictionary sometimes chooses it as the capacity.

Comment: @CodeInChaose: I suspect that *any* value will have degenerate cases when the whole system is considered. Feel free to pick better values – in a general purpose answer they are essentially arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the boxing issue chain your calls using a generic extension method on Int32

```
public static class HashHelper
{
    public static int InitialHash = 17; // Prime number
    private static int Multiplier = 23; // Different prime number

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Int32 GetHashCode<T>( this Int32 source, T next )
    {
        // comparing null of value objects is ok. See
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-sharp-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null
        if ( next == null )
        {
            return source;
        }
        unchecked
        {
            return source + next.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

}
```

then you can do

```
HashHelper
    .InitialHash
    .GetHashCode(field0)
    .GetHashCode(field1)
    .GetHashCode(field2);
```

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307020), it describes MD5 hashing.
Otherwise use GetHashCode().

Comment: OP isn't talking about cryptographic hashes, more like hash functions as used by `GetHashCode` etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @Richard & @LukeH - please read the question carefully he does not wants a optimal solution but a good one.

Comment: Check the updated question: this is a question about the implementation of `GetHashCode`.