# Weird behavior between null values and overloaded equal operator

Tags: c#, comparison-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# okay with comparing value types to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null)

Why value type as DateTime and Decimal whose the equality operator is overloaded can be compared with null value?

I always thought that value types are non-nullables values, but I'm allowed to write the following code:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime();

if(dateTime == null)
    //do something
```

The compilation doesn't throw an exception, however the comparison is always false.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there's an implicit conversion to `DateTime?` available from both sides. It's a bit of a corner case which isn't ideal, basically :(

In *some* cases it gives a warning, but not for all (so not here, for example).

For example, using `int`:

```
int x = 5;

if(x == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You'll get this warning:

> warning CS0472: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'