# Why does c# allow this? ( null checking to int)

Tags: c#, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# okay with comparing value types to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-sharp-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null)

Why does C# allow :

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyInt;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass m = new MyClass();
    if (m.MyInt == null) // <------------- ?
        Console.Write("......");
}
```

Resharper says "*expression is always false*" - which is obviously - *true* since `MyInt` is `int` and not `int?`

But how C# allow this to compile? The property will always be there and its type is `int`!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through testing if MyInt is null ?

Comment: @Eregrith Knowing .net better.

Comment: @Mehmet this is not my question....

Comment: So? `if (true == false)`, that compiles too.

Comment: @Schaliasos MyInt can't hold null . so your example is not the same

Comment: Why not? It'd be silly if the equality operator wouldn't accept certain operands.

Comment: study of declaration and initialization int will solve your problem

Comment: There isn't a reason it wouldn't compile, however it may get removed since it is meaningless. You could check the asm to see if it was removed.

Comment: @RoyiNamir And `true` can never be `false`; it's exactly the same.

Comment: study of declaration and initialization int will solve your problem

Comment: Eric Lippert already answered that, I think (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-sharp-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null)

Comment: i still wonder if int a=null; this leads to an error but if if(class.name==null) no error at compile time ...there is issue with the framework or something elase

Comment: Just as an aside, in release mode this provably unreachable code is not actually compiled into the final IL. This will only feature in debug (or non-optimised).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, this is simply for the same reason why would compile

```
if(false)
   Console.WriteLine("never get here");
```

Something that would never execute.

Worth mantioning that, yes you don't get error, but you get a warning on this.

Comment: @downvoter: reason or downvoting for hobby?

Comment: There are many people who love to downvote without explanation

Comment: I downvoted because I didn't believe it to be an answer to the question. It would have been more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: But `Console.Write(1 / 0);` does not compile.

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain ?