# C# Null int? returns 0 for ToString

Tags: c#

This obviously results in an error:

```
null.ToString();
```

Why does this ToString not get the same error:

```
int? foo = null;
foo.ToString(); // 0, why no error?
0 == foo; // false
null == foo; // true
null == 0; // false
```

I get that there is some internal magic going on, but it seems bizarre to me that foo.ToString() would return 0 when the value isn't equal to int 0.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do what you claim it does. `foo.ToString()` will return `"0"` only if the nullable `int` is in fact non-null. When it has the `null` value, `ToString()` returns the empty string `""`, exactly as the documentation promises it will.

Comment: Note that `null.ToString();` wouldn't even compile: "error CS0023: Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type '<null>'". Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates behaviour you don't understand - as Peter says, calling `ToString()` on a null value of any `Nullable<T>` will return an empty string.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I no longer have the original. Instead of assigning null to foo I was calling a class function that was returning null, I think the return type of the function was int?. A ToString call on the return type was an empty string I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a line-to-line analysis of your code.

```
null.ToString();
```

Here a method is called on a null reference. Of course exception would be thrown.

```
int? foo = null;
```

This creates a struct `foo` of type `Nullable<int>` on the stack, and has its `HasValue` property to false.

```
foo.ToString();
```

This calls the `ToString()` method of `Nullable<T>`, which is overridden to return an empty string (`""`).**(In your question you said that returns `0`. This is not true.)** Note that calling an overridden method directly on a **value type** does not cause boxing.

```
0 == foo
```

This works and returns false because `0` is converted into a `Int32?` which contains a value, but `foo` does not contain any value. See [this answer about nullable type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-sharp-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null) about and [documentation about lifted operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#lifted-operators)

```
null == foo;
```

Works and returns `true` because `null` is converted to `Int32?` which does not contain any value. This equals `foo`, which also doesn't contain any value.

```
null == 0
```

Works and returns `false` because `null` is converted to `Int32?` and `0` is converted to `Int32?` but the former contains no value.