# Why can I check DateTime for null, even though it is a value type?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, null, value-type

This compiles without error or warning, how is this possible?

```
if (DateTime.Now == null) { }
```

*EDIT:*

It's getting even better:

If I do the same with `Decimal`, `int` or a user defined `struct`, I get a compiler error.

What is the difference?

Comment: It will always be false.

Comment: You may have found a minor glitch in the compiler.  If you try to assign null to a DateTime you get:  Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type

Comment: I think I accidentally deleted your comment, but I did reply to your follow-on point about primitives...

Comment: @Steve see the "connect" issue I linked to - it isn't new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Why can TimeSpan and Guid Structs be compared to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225949/why-can-timespan-and-guid-structs-be-compared-to-null)

Good explanation in the answer here

Several code-analysis tools (like Resharper) will flag it as "always false" and subsequent code as unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

If you put code in the block, it *used* to warn of unreachable code, but IIRC this warning disappeared (the issue has been reported).

As for "why"; because there is a legal implicit conversion (box or nullable) that allows the test to work as per the language requirements. However, it will always be `false`, and IIRC the compiler is smart enough to excise the clearly unreachable code (shame about the warning).

Comment: See also: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=348850

Comment: @codymanix it should be a *warning* IIRC (not an error), and it kinda depends on the operators defined. I seem to recall the connect issue stated the combinations..

Answer (score 2):

You can compare any value type to null. However, it will always be false because a value type can never be null.

As to why it's allowed, ALL types in .NET (including those that inherit more directly from System.ValueType) inherit from System.Object, which defines an == operator. That means that every type can be compared for referential equality. However, ValueTypes will never evaluate to null because the CLR always ensures, at very deep levels, that ValueType "references" always have a value even when boxed as reference types.