# Why is comparing a struct to NULL legal in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# okay with comparing value types to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-sharp-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null)

Consider the following code with the TimeSpan, which is a struct:

```
// will not compile - illegal
TimeSpan ts = null;
```

However, the following code does compile and is legal, though the expression is always false:

```
if (ts == null)
    Console.WriteLine("this line will never be hit");
```

Can someone tell me why it's invalid to set a struct to a NULL, but it's ok to compare it to one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022425/comparing-structs-to-null, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648115/how-can-an-object-not-be-compared-to-null, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225949/why-can-timespan-and-guid-structs-be-compared-to-null, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-sharp-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null

Comment: If you couldn't compare structs to null, what would you do with Nullable<T>?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Better question is; how would you implement `Nullable<T>` as a `struct`?  (of course, you couldn't).  `Nullable<T>` could of course be implemented as a reference type

Comment: @EdS. but `Nullable<T>` *is* a struct.

Comment: @phoog: Right, that's what I was getting at :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fails to compile for me:

```
struct Foo { }

class Program
{       
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var f = new Foo();
        if( f == null ) { }
    }
}
```

> Error  1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ConsoleApplication3.Foo' and 'null'

Comment: @AngryHacker: It's because `TimeSpan` overloads the `==` operator (I didn't catch that at first).  My point is that your question "Why is comparing a struct to NULL legal in C#?" isn't complete;  you can't, unless you overload the equality operator to accept it.  minitech has a better response.

Answer (score 7):

It's still legal because you can overload the `==` operator for `struct`s.

```
struct AmNull {
    public static bool operator ==(AmNull a, object b) {
        return b == null;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(AmNull a, object b) {
        return b != null;
    }
}

...

Console.WriteLine(new AmNull() == null); // True
```

Comment: @AngrHacker: I think you should chose this response as the accepted answer.  It covers my response but expands upon it to explain why this behavior is present.